# ¿Como subir un archivo modificado en github en un repositorio en el que soy colaborador?

Tags: git, github

Tengo que modificar un archivo y subirlo a github en un repositorio en el que soy colaborador,  el problema es que no sé como hacerlo, lo único que sé es subir un archivo desde mi repositorio pero no desde otro en el que soy colaborador.

Intente con lo siguiente :

ruta en la carpeta donde quiere clonar el archivo git clonar http:/github....

```
git branch yo2019
git remote add origin pego el link del repositorio
git push -u origin master
```

con el ultimo comando me pone que tengo que escribir  usuario y contraseña de la cuenta de github , y pongo los de mi cuenta,  pero cuando al ejecutar esto me sale error 403 .

Se que estoy haciendo mal por que me perdí , que debería hacer?
Hace poco empece con esto tenganme paciencia jaja :/

Comment: Esta pregunta revivió sin necesidad y sería más fácil para el mundo si tuviese una respuesta aceptada (pues, si alguna de las respuestas resolvió la pregunta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es una buena practica el subir tus cambios directamente a master. Si eres un colaborador de un proyecto, lo correcto seria que hicieras una Pull Request: `https://yangsu.github.io/pull-request-tutorial/`

Se trata de un proceso que implicaria al resto del equipo. En esencia, una `Pull Request` es una solicitud de cambio sobre el proyecto.

Primero creas una rama (como has hecho en tu ejemplo)
luego, con tu codigo, subes dicha rama

`git push -u origin yo2019`

Luego, en github, tienes que ir al repositorio, situarte en la rama, y pulsar el boton `pull request`. Asegurate que el destino de esa PR es mezclar sobre el master (que es lo que te interesa)

Por ultimo, cuando la gente de tu proyecto apruebe dicha PR, podras utilizar el boton de merge del propio github.

Este proceso se debe hacer cuando sois muchos colaboradores. De esa manera, tienes que pasar por la aprobacion de tu equipo. Tambien se utiliza si eres colaborador de un proyecto general. En ese caso, el dueño del proyecto y otros podran revisar tu colaboracion, comentarla e integrarla en caso de que les interese.

Answer (score 2):

No se si lo que quieres realmente es crear un nuevo branch y subir contenido a ese nuevo branch, voy a ponerlo de la siguiente manera:

dentro de la ruta del git en el que estas trabajando ejecutarías para crear un nuevo branch:

```
git checkout -b yo2019
```

después añadirías el fichero concreto con el que estés trabajando en ese branch:

```
git add tufichero
git commit -m "comentario sobre tu cambio"
```

ahora como este branch no existe en remoto tendrías que ejecutar:

```
git push --set-upstream origin yo2019
```

y ya tendrías un branch en el que trabajar y que una vez terminado y revisada la vida util de este branch así como validados los cambios que vas a aplicar a master desde aquí podrías terminar haciendo un merge contra otra rama como devel o similar.

Te recomiendo que si tienes dudas de como funciona esto que te he indicado lo hagas contra un nuevo repo de test en git hasta que te sientas cómodo y entiendas lo que esta ocurriendo.

Answer (score 0):

Después de que haces los cambios en el documento y los guardas, desde la carpeta local que tienes y que esta relacionada con tu repositorio, das clic derecho en la carpeta y seleccionas "Git Bash Here", eso te abre una terminal y en ella antes de subir tus cambios te recomiendo ingresar "git pull", para que antes de subir lo que tienes, descargues todos los cambios realizados por otros colaboradores, ya que eso puede ser un problema cuando otra persona trabaja en la misma sección, posterior a eso, ingresas "git status", para visualizar los cambios que has hecho, ingresas "git add ." para cargar tus cambios, nuevamente ingresas "git status" y veras que tus cambios ya se cargaron, posteriormente subes tus archivos con "git commit -m "Nombredelcambio""y finalmente para cargar esos cambios en tu repositorio ingresas "git push", de esta forma podrás actualizar la carpeta de tu gitHub y veras los cambios que realizaste, te recomiendo tener cuidado en la cantidad de cambios que realices, ya que si requiere una cantidad de memoria mayor a 100Mb, no se podrán subir tus cambios y tendras que cancelar o barrar tu "commit".